# Using Pandas & Win32com for excel macro

Tags: python, vba, pandas

I am trying to read muilty excel file, and merge to [A] file which include macro.

so i try to use this methhood

1.choose file

```
def openinputfile():
    global input_filename
    input_filename = askopenfilenames(filetypes=(
    ("Excel files", "*.xls;*.xlsx")
```

2.next merge files with pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for f in [input_filename]:
    data = pd.read_excel(f, 'Sheet1')
    df = df.append(data)
```

3.and do marco in excel

```
xl = comDispatch('Excel.Application')
xl.Workbooks.Open("Macros.xls", True)
xl.Run("Macros.xls!Macro_1")
```

choose file is todly work, but it dosen't work since 2.next merge files with pandas. There are so many error code that i can't paste...
Am i try the right way? How can i change it..?

sorry for Rudimentary question, I use python 3.7